# Making apps come live on Facebook

Tags: facebook-apps, social-media, facebook-app-settings

The problem I'm having is that I created a new app on `WooBox.com` that has a connection to Facebook.

I created the app for a `HTML` **Fangate tab** to be seen on Facebook, but I get a message that the app can't be seen because it is not live, whatever that means. Every time I try to test the app the page never stops loading. I even restarted my computer but to no avail.

Comment: FYI: “Fangate” sounds like you want to show content to people only when they like the page that the tab is on – and that is not allowed by Facebook any more.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that.

Comment: All of this is kind of moot now since the app appeared on my page. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the site [developer.facebook.com](http://developer.facebook.com) select your app, go to `Status&Review` option and there you can make your app live.

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but every time I go to the developer page, like status and review that you mentioned, and click on it the page doesn't stop loading. That loading icon just keep going round and round. Next to my app there is a funny icon, like a warning sign. I don't know what it means, yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to  understand that if you are developing the app probably is set to **not** live and you have to add the testers and the developers in section `roles`.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

You also can set to  live :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/security

Comment: I was in that part. I applied the tester, but the page didn't stop loading. When I came back to Facebook I saw the app tab. I'm still trying to find the role section you mentioned. I would have gotten back sooner but I'm been really busy trying to get the homework done. Facebook for me has not been easy.

Comment: I know it's not live because the message said it wasn't live. Every time I click to make it live, the page won't stop loading,